# The applications of Picard's theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If there any explanation  for the steps that will use to solve this IVP, I will be very thankful.

Consider the initial value problem

$$
x' = x^{2}, \quad x(0) = 2
$$

with

$$R = \{ (t, x) : \lvert t \rvert \le a, \quad \lvert x - 2 \rvert \le b, \quad a, b \gt 0\}$$

Find the largest interval in Picard's theorem such that the solution exists and is unique.

Comment: What does "largest integral" mean?

Comment: Do you mean 'largest interval'?

Comment: Just solve the equation, and you'll *see* the answer... (From $dx/dt=x^2$, either $x$ is identically zero, or else $dx/x^2=dt$, etc.)